# How to parse time durations from Strings and add them?

Tags: java

I need to parse two Strings in `HH:MM` format in Java:

```
String time1="10:45";
String time2="02:30";
```

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "calculate two Strings"?

Comment: What do you mean by "calculate" here? What have you tried?

Comment: calculate hours and minutes to give me total = 13:15

Comment: @mohamedtarek So you want to add the times?

Comment: The Problem is that i retrieve rows from Oracle DB in This Format HH:MM i need to loop on them and calculate the totals hours and minutes

Comment: Do you mean "total" as in "duration"? What if this total is larger than 24 hours?

Comment: Is parsing or adding the issue?

Comment: @Tichodroma no problem if the total is bigger than 24 hours

Comment: what if the total is more than 99 hours and 99 minutes?

Comment: Yes it can: time1="52:35", time2="49:42", sum="102:17" (or 1h42:17). You didn't specify any constraints in your original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stupid but simple:

```
String time1 = "10:45";
String time2 = "02:30";

String[] split1 = time1.split(":");
String[] split2 = time2.split(":");

int total = 60 * Integer.parseInt(split1[0]) +
            Integer.parseInt(split1[1]) +
            60 * Integer.parseInt(split2[0]) +
            Integer.parseInt(split2[1]);

int hours = total / 60;
int minutes = total - hours * 60;
System.out.println(hours + ":" + minutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get the difference? have a look at the SimpleDateFormat, perhaps you use that to create a Date and then calculate on that.

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment.

Comment: @Tichodroma ceci n'est pas une pipe

Comment: For a proper value of "This".

Answer (score 0):

Use SimpleDateFormat to get teh dates

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse("10:20");
```

Then you can add the dates together.

You may have to do some logic to cope with times where the dateas go over different days. I would recommend using JodaTime for any date manipulation.

Not sure if this is relevant as not sure what the actual question is....